# POST to Notifications API works fine with "user-id-1" but doesn't work with "user-id-2"

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to server-side POST to Notifications API but I can't make it work consistently.

As required in the
[Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#impl)

I am using the App Access Token 
to post to Facebook's Notifications API.

Both users have authorized the app.

The notification-post works fine, when using "specific-user-id-1/notifications" and returns {"success":true}

When using "specific-user-id-2/notifications" 
The same lines of code don't work, 
and return
"(OAuthException - #2) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."

Should I change something in the way I post to the Notifications API ?

This was also submitted to facebook bugs... just in case.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
fb.AppId = "APP_ID";
fb.AppSecret = "APP_SECRET";
fb.AccessToken = "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN";

dynamic nparams = new ExpandoObject();
nparams.access_token = "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN";
nparams.template = "testing";
nparams.href = "";

var response = fb.Post("RECIPIENT_FACEBOOK_USER_ID/notifications", nparams);
```

**UPDATE**
Notifications are working fine now. (without code changes)
It seems that this was a Facebook problem.

**UPDATE 2**
1 day after the previous update... not working again...

Comment: This is exactly the same problem I'm facing right now, accessing the API via PHP. Did you find some helpful info in the end?